# How to keep alive mounted network drives on sleep?

Tags: networking, macos, mac, lan, sleep

I'm copying a vast amount of files from one Mac (11.2.3) to the other (10.13.6).

When the destination Mac goes to sleep, the copying process fails. Even though the Energy Saver settings are set to "Wake for network access".

Is there a way to prevent this from happening (without setting computer sleep to never)?

Comment: Try to disable "Enable Power Nap" in the Energy Saver settings.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for getting back! Unfortunately, however, there is no such thing on High Sierra.

Comment: Temporarily, you can keep the Mac from sleeping without changing settings: https://www.howtogeek.com/227561/how-to-prevent-your-mac-from-sleeping-without-changing-any-settings/

Answer (score 1):

To disable sleep via GUI in 10.13.6:

System Prefs - Power Saver - Computer Sleep - Drag all the way to the right (Never go to sleep)

Via Terminal:

```
sudo pmset disablesleep 1
```